# Fabric JS - How to check if an object collides with another object on its Y-axis(Vertically)

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to maintain a minimum vertical gap between different sized image objects on a canvas. 
I'm unable to figure out how can minimum gap be maintained with the closest vertical object if there's any. If somehow I can get the objects vertically(Y-axis) colliding with the currently placed object I think that'll be enough to maintain the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by iterating over each object of the canvas and getting and checking if the iterating object's bounding rectangle **top+height** is greater or equal to object's bounding rectangle **top** which needs to be placed. Here's is sample of the code

```js
const presentObjs = canvas.getObjects();
let objectToBeplaced = presentObjs[3]; //random object just for example, please change according to your need.
let currentObj = objectToBePlaced;
const presentObjsCount = presentObjs.length;
const gapY = 10;//10 points gap vertically
let j;
for (j = 0; j < presentObjsCount; j++)
{
            const obj = presentObjs[j];
            if (obj === currentObj) {
              continue;
            }
            const objBox = obj.getBoundingRect();
            const objW = Math.ceil(Math.abs(objBox.width));
            const objLeft = Math.ceil(Math.abs(objBox.left));
            const objH = Math.ceil(Math.abs(objBox.height));
            const objTop = Math.ceil(Math.abs(objBox.top));

            const cObjBox = currentObj.getBoundingRect();
            const cObjW = Math.ceil(Math.abs(cObjBox.width));
            const cObjLeft = Math.ceil(Math.abs(cObjBox.left));
            const cObjH = Math.ceil(Math.abs(cObjBox.height));
            const cObjTop = Math.ceil(Math.abs(cObjBox.top));

            const a = cObjLeft;
            const b = cObjLeft + cObjW;
            const x = objLeft;
            const y = objLeft + objW;

                if ((x >= a && x <= b) || (y >= a && y <= b) || (a >= x && b <= x) || (a >= y && b <= y)) { //Checks if both object has intersection on Y-axis
              if ((cObjTop - (objTop + objH)) < gapY && (cObjTop - (objTop + objH)) >= 0) { //checks  if gap is less than needed
                currentObj.set({ top: objTop + objH + gapY });
                currentObj.setCoords();
              }
            }
}
canvas.renderAll();
```

Feel free to ask any questions or doubt if you have.